# Add to a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, object

How can I add: `"headers": { time: new Date().getTime() }` to a Javscript object:

```
{
  "1": 3.7,
  "2": 0.5,
  "3": 1.0,
  "4": 60,
  "5": 180,
}
```

So the resulting object is (for example):

```
{
  "1": 3.7,
  "2": 0.5,
  "3": 1.0,
  "4": 60,
  "5": 180,
  "headers": { "time" : 1234 },
}
```

If I use `push` I get a `“Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o”` and I'm unsure of how to wrap the headers if I use object notation to add.

Comment: `obj.headers = { time: new Date().getTime() }`

Comment: [Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1184123)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var a = {
  "1": 3.7,
  "2": 0.5,
  "3": 1.0,
  "4": 60,
  "5": 180,
};

a.headers = { "time" : 1234 };
//OR
a["headers"] = { "time" : 1234 };
```